# Pop first element of OrderedSet

Tags: set, nim-lang

How do I pop the first element of an [OrderedSet](https://nim-lang.org/docs/sets.html#OrderedSet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you iterate and exclude the element:

```
import std / sets

proc popFirst[T](o: var OrderedSet[T]): T =
  for elem in o:
    o.excl elem
    return elem

var o = toOrderedSet([5, 3, 2])

echo o.popFirst() # 5
echo o # {3, 2}
```

[playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=3PKv)